# error MtSQL 1048 cannot be null

Tags: mysql

```
drop database BaseDatos;
create database if not exists BaseDatos;
use BaseDatos;

create table if not exists genre(
id_genero int not null auto_increment,
nombre_genero varchar (45) not null,
primary key (id_genero))ENGINE=INNODB;

create table if not exists user (
id_usuario int not null auto_increment, 
nombre varchar (45)not null, 
password varchar (45)not null,
primary key (id_usuario))ENGINE=INNODB;
create  table if not exists singer (
id_interprete int not null auto_increment,
nombre_interprete varchar (45)not null,
nacionalidad varchar (45)not null,
primary key (id_interprete))ENGINE=INNODB;
create table if not exists song (
id_cancion int not null auto_increment,
nombre_cancion varchar (45) not null,
id_interprete int not null,
duracion int not null,
tamanio int not null,
id_genero int not null,
primary key (id_cancion),
foreign key (id_interprete)references singer(id_interprete),
foreign key (id_genero)references genre(id_genero) )ENGINE=INNODB;
##########
use BaseDatos;
insert into user(id_usuario,nombre,password) values (NULL,"jor","123");
insert into genre(id_genero,nombre_genero)values (NULL,"");
insert into song(id_cancion,nombre_cancion,duracion,tamanio)values('',"",'','');
insert into singer(id_interprete,nombre_interprete,nacionalidad)values('',"","");
```

cuando lo ejecuto me marca error 1048

Comment: Hola! mira por favor [ask]. buscaste el error? que encontraste? te fijaste que podia ser de todo esto?

Comment: si,cuando quiero insertar datos en la tabla genre me marca este error insert into genre(id_genero,nombre_genero)values (NULL,"");                     Error Code: 1048. Column 'id_genero' cannot be null

Comment: Aja... y te fijaste como creaste el campo? id_genero int not null auto_increment, y que valores le pasas en el insert (null)...

Comment: No se que otra clase de ayuda esperas, si el error te dice clarito que pasa

Comment: lo hice igual que el de user y ese si me inserta los datos ,por eso es que no entiendo porque en el insert into user esta bien y el de insert into genre esta mal ya que practicamente tiene  los mismos campos al igual que singer,song

Comment: Vos estas seguro, que las tablas estan creadas de esa forma? porque user deberia dar el mismo error. pero vos decis create table if not exists, por lo tanto si existia, no la creo, y capaz ya estaba creada de otra forma. Hace un drop de todas las tablas, volve a crearlas, y si no mostra que efectivamente carga los datos en las otras tablas que decis.

Comment: pues si lo hice , pero aun me aparecen errores para hacer el insert into y como tambien lo estoy haciendo con php

Comment: proba esto: insert into genre(nombre_genero)values (""); y decime que pasa

Comment: si si quedo pero.. Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`softmusic`.`song`, CONSTRAINT `song_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_interprete`) REFERENCES `singer` (`id_interprete`))

Comment: y el error que te dice? que tu cancion debe tener un interprete valido, porque asi lo escribiste vos. La principal pregunta aca es.. sabes lo que hace ese script? sabes como se cargan datos? sabes como funcionan esas constrain?

Comment: la verdad soy  nueva en esto y sinceramente me esta costando mucho :(

Comment: entonces la mejor recomendacion que tengo es que leas sobre primary keys y foreing keys. Que trates de entender que hace ese script. porque hace cada una de esas cosas, y sobre todo para que hace esas cosas que hace. No se si esto es un ejercicio o que cosa, puedo solucionar todos los errores que te aparezcan, pero no vas a aprender nada. y otra cosa es leer que quiere decir cada error y entender porque se da.